# Use nested generics without a lot of code

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I would like to create a linq like extension method to get all items from a hierarchical structure like a tree.

This is my extension

```
public static List<T> GetAllRecursive<T, TU>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, TU> func) where TU : IEnumerable<T> {
    var allList = new List<T>();
    var toAdd = list.ToList();
    while(true) {
        allList.AddRange(toAdd);
        var childs = toAdd.SelectMany(x => func(x)).ToList();
        if(childs.Count == 0) {
            return allList;
        }
        toAdd = childs;
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
var allGuidelines = Guidelines.GetAllRecursive(x => (IEnumerable<MachineGuidelineTreeItemViewModel>)x.Children);
```

**How can I improve this method so I don't need to cast every time I use this?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the return type of Children?

Comment: and why do you need to cast it to IEnumerable at all? Isn't x.Children an IEnumerable<> already? Is it a more generic type, for example, IEnumerable<object> or something like that? If so, how do you know that it's safe to cast it to IE<MachineGuidelineTreeItemViewModel> ?

Comment: Children is a BindableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>

Comment: I need to cast, because the compiler does not understand BindableCollection<T> is a IEnumerable<T> the problem is the generics.

Comment: If Children is `BindableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>` it means it can contain any descendant of `TreeItemViewModel`, not just `MachineGuidelineTreeItemViewModel`, so it's not safe to cast it to `IEnumerable<MachineGuidelineTreeItemViewModel>`. You might know it's safe at runtime but compiler sure cannot.

Comment: Try changing your definition of BindableCollection to BindableCollection<MachineGuidelineTreeItemViewModel> and it will work without cast

Comment: I can not change the definition of Children because it's from the base class TreeItemViewModel.

Comment: @Evk if I cast to (IEnumerable<TreeItemViewModel>) I get an error, because it has to be the same class like x and Guidelines is a list with GuidelineTreeItemViewModels

Comment: I didn't suggest to do that. I just mean as is - you cannot avoid the cast, because `BindableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>` is _not_ `IEnumerable<GuidelineTreeItemViewModel>`. Does it even work with the cast (no exceptions at runtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `TU` type parameter, and use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on `IEnumerable` instead:

```
public static List<T> GetAllRecursive<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, IEnumerable> func) {
    var allList = new List<T>();
    var toAdd = list.ToList();
    while(true) {
        allList.AddRange(toAdd);
        var childs = toAdd.SelectMany(x => func(x).OfType<T>()).ToList();
        if(childs.Count == 0) {
            return allList;
        }
        toAdd = childs;
    }
}
```

This approach is more lenient, because it lets you pass functions that return a mixed bag of items, with the method filtering it by type.

Comment: I think maybe the `toAdd` variable and `childs` variable, while required, do not necessarily have to be `List`s. Probably won't make much of a difference, but I'm thinking it's possible to avoid that `ToList()` call when assigning `childs`...

Comment: @BurnsBA I agree, there's definitely some room for making this method even more general. I went with OP's implementation to address one specific shortcoming, while keeping the rest of his code in place.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for now i have a small call: `var allGuidelines = Guidelines.GetAllRecursive(x => x.Children);` - Thanks